# Calling startActivityForResult() within OnItemClickListener()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-gridview

I've implemented a 'home screen' for my application, which consists of a gridview containing icons and text. This works fine, and I can add an OnItemClickListener so that tapping an icon will create a toast, for example. But I'm not sure how to call startActivityForResult() from here. I could pass in the application context and use this to create the intent etc, but this doesn't feel like the right way of doing it.

My code looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.icons_gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new HomeScreenAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                //need to start new activity 1 from here
                break;
            case 1:
                //need to start new activity 2 from here
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help,

TLB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 (my prefered method)**

Passing ActivityName.this as context is the way I do it. For example

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.icons_gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new HomeScreenAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            //need to start new activity 2 from here
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

**Method 2**

You could pass `getApplicationContext()` as the context;

**Method 3**

Having a `Context mContext` field is a common method. Set it at the start of your `onCreate` then use `mContext` to start your activities.

```
private Context mContext;
```

then

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.title);

    mContext = this;

    ...
 }
```

Then you can start a new activity using mContext as the context parameter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Method 1 works perfectly, as suggested by Jin35 as well. Method 2 is what I was trying to avoid, as it didn't seem like the right way of doing it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class));
```

and everything is easy

Answer (score 0):

The context should be the context of the current activity.  'this' would work admirably.